# Can't remove arduino library

Tags: windows, arduino, libraries

I'm trying to remove a library from my arduino IDE. I've read the discussion about why there is no delete button in the GUI. So I have to remove it as files (on my windows machine). But I find libraries in many different folders, and still removing them does not seem to actually remove them from the IDE. How do I do this?

My sketch folder has a libraries folder, and there is one in program files:

```
C:\Users\MyUsername\Documents\Arduino\libraries
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries
```

It's not in any of those.

Then I found this:

```
C:\Users\MyUsername\AppData\Local\Arduino15\staging\libraries
```

There I found the library as a zipfile, and removed it. I also removed it from the `package_index.json` that is located two folders up. Started Arduino IDE, and it is still there, and it automatically comes back in the package_index.json file.

How do I get rid of it?

Comment: Why do you need to remove a library?  Why not simply just not use it if you don't need it?

Answer (score 0):

All your third party libraries are stored into your Arduino folder within your home user directory. So you must to delete them from there. They're always decompressed folders, non zipped ones.

Arduino IDE loads automatically them and restore the descriptor file of necessary every time that starts.

Original libraries cannot be deleted from other locations (ok, you'd won't to delete them...).